# Directly access UserControl's DataContext, without intermediary DepProps: Possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have, f.i. a Window and A UserControl, which UC I use twice in the Window.
The UC has a bunch of TextBoxes and Labels.
To access the Content of the Label, f.i., you define a DepProp in the IC's code-behind.

A lot of Textboxes, a lot op DepProps.

Boring.

is there a way around that? Can I not access somehow the Content property of the (eg.) Label inside  the UC from outside without these DepProps in between?

My two UC's have different objects of the same Type as DataContext

Comment: The elements in the UserControl's XAML can of course directly bind to properties of the current (inherited) DataContext. Didn't you try that?

Comment: Indeed. Thanks. Feels like you twisted my head 180 degrees :D.